# how to define a friend template function of a template class

Tags: friend-function, template-function

I've a Template Class `array_T` which is a general purpose array and a Template function `linear search TEMPLATE.h` and its declared  as friend for the class `arrayTemplate.h`  so it could be able to use the class's member function `getArraySize()` and the class's data member `a` which is a dynamic allocation array

arrayTemplate.h

```
    #ifndef arrayTemplate
    #define arrayTemplate
    #include"linear search TEMPLATE.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
class array_T  {

private:
    T *a;
    int arraySize;

public : 
    friend void linearSearch(array_T object);

    array_T(int s) {
        arraySize = s;
        a = new T[arraySize];

        for (int i= 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    ~array_T() {
        delete[]a;
    }

    void setArray() {
        for (int  i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
            cout << "Enter the elements of the array " << endl;
            cin >> a[i];
        }
    }

    void getArray() {
        for (int  i=0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    int getArraySize() {
        return arraySize;
    }


};
#endif
```

linear search TEMPLATE.h

```
#include"arrayTemplate.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
//void linearSearch(T desiredData, int arraySize, T *elemnts) {
void linearSearch(array_T<T> object , T desiredData) {
    int arraySize = object.getArraySize();
    int loc = -1;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {

        if (object.a[i] == desiredData) {
            loc = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (loc > 0) {
        cout << "the Item is found at position " << i + 1 << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "the item is not found ";
    }

}
```

main.cpp

```
  #include"arrayTemplate.h"
   #include"linear search TEMPLATE.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;



int main() {

    array_T<int> myArray(7);
    myArray.setArray();

    linearSearch(myArray,50)

return 0 ; 
}
```

these are the errors i got

> linear search template.h(8): error C2065: 'array_T': undeclared
>   identifier
>
> linear search template.h(8): error C2065: 'object': undeclared
>   identifier
>
> linear search template.h(8): error C2275: 'T': illegal use of this
>   type as an expression
>
> linear search template.h(6): note: see declaration of 'T'
>
> linear search template.h(8): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')'
>   before identifier 'desiredData'
>
> main.cpp(14): error C2660: 'linearSearch': function does not take 2
>   arguments
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========